# jquery dynamically inserted attr not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jqueryMobile :

```
 <div id="header"> 
  <h1>conent</h1>
 </div>
```

now in .js file :

```
 $("#header").attr("data-role","header");
```

This not works , but if i did :

```
 <div id="header" data-role="header"> 
  <h1>conent</h1>
 </div>
```

It works properly , but why when we are inserting attribute `data-role` dynamically through jquery it does`nt work?

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`? Could you please describe what do you expect and what is not happening?

Comment: @gaurav do you load jquery core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What matters here is the time at which you are adding the attribute to the `#header` div. I would suggest that you bind to the pagebeforecreate event. This way you are adding the attribute before JQM initializes the page. i.e.

```
​$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function(){
    $("#header").attr("data-role","header");
});​
```

Here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/codaniel/wJdvK/1/

Here is a quote from docs.

**pagebeforecreate**

Triggered on the page being initialized, before most plugin auto-initialization occurs.

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just inserted into the dom!' );
});
```

Note that by binding to pagebeforecreate, you can manipulate markup before jQuery Mobile's default widgets are auto-initialized. For example, say you want to add data-attributes via JavaScript instead of in the HTML source, this is the event you'd use.

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
  // manipulate this page before its widgets are auto-initialized
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrap your code inside the `pageinit`-event?

Take a look at the [jQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html).

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function(e){
    $("#header").attr("data-role","header");
});
```

Or the proper way (exactly the same, just a bit shorter):

```
$(document).bind('pagebeforecreate', function(e){
    $("#header").data("role","header");
});
```

Comment: Did you try both ways? On a mobile device?